# Verilog Timing Simulation: +notimingcheck versus +no_notifier

Tags: verilog

For gate level simulation that has been annotated with an SDF file,  when there's a setup/hold violations on a flip-flop the following will happen by default:

- (1) The FF's output will change to 'X'
- (2) a timing violation assertion will be generated

But, what's the effect of `+notimingcheck` verses `+no_notifier`.  Can you use both of these Verilog compilation flags together?

Here's my guess below: (Is this correct or just plain wrong?)

- when `+notimingcheck` is specified, item (2) is disabled, and an assertion will not be generated
- when `+no_notifier` is specified, item (1) is disabled, the output will not change to 'X'
  (which is good for running gate level design having multiple clock domains).

Right or Wrong? or almost right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, those two options are not part of the IEEE Std for Verilog (1800-2017, for example).  That means that their behavior is defined by the simulator, and not all simulators are guaranteed to support them.  The simulators I use by Cadence and Synopsys do happen to support them.

Secondly, notifier behavior depends on how they are used in the Verilog code, and they are optional.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 31.6 *Notifiers: user-defined responses to timing violations*.  Most standard cell libraries do make use of them, but you need to look at the Verilog code to see how they are implemented in your case.  Your FF may set the output to X when the notifier changes value, but this is not the case in general for timing checks.

Here is some code I had lying around which can demonstrate their usage:

```
module tb;
    reg  [3:0] addr;
    wire [3:0] addr2 = addr;
    reg ntfy_reg_p;
    reg ntfy_reg_n;

    specify
        $width(posedge addr2, 50, 30, ntfy_reg_p);
        $width(negedge addr2, 50, 30, ntfy_reg_n);
    endspecify

    always @(ntfy_reg_p or ntfy_reg_n) begin
        $display("Error: width violation at %0t", $time);
    end

    initial begin
        $monitor("addr2 = %b, %0t", addr2, $time);
        #100 addr = 4'b0000;
        #40  addr = 4'b0100;    // get violation here
        #100 addr = 4'b0000;
        #100 addr = 4'b1111;
        #10 $finish;
    end
endmodule
```

---

When I run a simulation without either switch on Cadence, I get a **simulator-specific** warning message, and I see my **user-defined** notifier `Error` message:

```
addr2 = xxxx, 0
addr2 = 0000, 100

Warning!  Timing violation
           $width( negedge addr2[2]:100 NS,  : 140 NS,  50 : 50 NS );
            File: ./tb.sv, line = 9
           Scope: tb
            Time: 140 NS

Error: width violation at 140
addr2 = 0100, 140
addr2 = 0000, 240
addr2 = 1111, 340
```

---

When I run with just `+no_notifier`, I get the warning, but not the error.  This means the notifier was ignored:

```
addr2 = xxxx, 0
addr2 = 0000, 100

Warning!  Timing violation
           $width( negedge addr2[2]:100 NS,  : 140 NS,  50 : 50 NS );
            File: ./tb.sv, line = 9
           Scope: tb
            Time: 140 NS

addr2 = 0100, 140
addr2 = 0000, 240
addr2 = 1111, 340
```

---

When I run with just `+notimingchecks`, I get neither the warning nor the error:

```
addr2 = xxxx, 0
addr2 = 0000, 100
addr2 = 0100, 140
addr2 = 0000, 240
addr2 = 1111, 340
```

When I run with both (`+notimingchecks +no_notifier`), I get neither the warning nor the error, as above.

All of this is consistent with my simulator documentation for these options.